# Q: C# - How To Enable / Disable Button According To If ListboxItem Selected

Tags: c#, button, listbox

I have a listbox and I want to do it. If my listbox is empty or not empty but no item selected, I want to disable button. But if listbox is not empty and it has a selected item, I want to enable button. I tried this but it doesn't work;

```
        if (lb.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if(lb.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Thank you for answers.

Comment: winforms? wpf? Do you get an error or what "doesn't work"? We may need to see more code to help.

Comment: Windows Form Application. Not error but it doesn't work. It never disable.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `else if`, just use else:

```
if (lb.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
   button1.Enabled = false;
}
else 
{
  button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work again. Where should I add this code exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You set the button to disabled at first, and then on your listbox `<your listboxid>_OnSelecIndexChanged` event check for the selected value and enable the button.

Comment: I don't know how can I apply this method, I'm going to try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to listbox the SelectedIndexChanged event

In the properties of your listbox search for SelectedIndexChanged, then double click on it

[image]

[Winforms selected index changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (lb.SelectedIndex == -1)
   {
     button1.Enabled = false;
   }
   else 
   {
     button1.Enabled = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answer. Where should I add it? In form1 or somewhere else?